# Display the table on click in SSRS report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS report. I have the default view of the report which displays some data. I have make a link for "more Info" on click of which i have to display the detailed table. 
Can anybody plz give me the steps to do the same.

Note : i already have a default data which is loaded as soon as the report comes up. I have sued 2 parameters to this. To display the detailed table on click of more info i have to take the new parameter. Can you please suggest me the

```
1.steps on creating the parameter to pass to details tables.
2.Set the value on the "more info" link so that i can use the value to evaluate the table.
3. How do i use this passed parameter in the details table.
```

Comment: Is the detailed table a new report? Or a table in current report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would create a new parameter called "MoreInfo" or something you want to call it, and create it as a boolean with default value "false". Then on your link I would create an action and send "true" as the value of the parameter you just created. If you have both the default and detailed table in the same report you are going to you can choose the current report in the "Specify report" dropdown.

You can then set the visibility of your details table to "hidden" if the parameter "MoreInfo" is false and show it if the value is true.

Edit: Created a quick demo:
In order to set visibility you can use the following in the tablix visibility:

```
=IIF(Parameters!MoreInfo.Value = false, true, false)
```

[image: Create parameter]

[image: Both tablixes]

[image: Tablix properties]

[image: Tablix visibility]

[image: Default]

[image: Details]

[image: Action box]

Comment: Hello thanku very much. The explanation is very clear and i followed the same. Its working half way.   --------------                                           1). I am passing parameters as hidden.
2). I want to set one defalut value say 0. 
3). I have 3 more-info links. from whcih i have to pass the value for the parameter. (say 1,2,3 for each)
4). Based on the value passed from the text box to the parameter , i am unsing  that value in the query to get the result.
--------------
The issue i am facing is: the value is not getting passed to the table. I am not getting any data in the table.

Comment: Looks like the parameter is not getting assigned a value from text box.

Comment: It sounds like something is missing from in the action you are performing if a parameter is not getting a value. I have updated my answer with an image of the action being done. I am only showing for the "MoreInfo" parameter. You probably have to add the other parameters you have in this action. You can just use the parametervalue as the Value if it is supposed to be the same.

Comment: Thank for solving my issue. And i understood the much better now.. thanks for all the help..